# I am trying to write a query for below scenario splitting one table into 2 as below

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench

DB : MYSQL WORKBENCH

Please find my below question, Could you please help me on this,

Existing table with columns as and rows as `( 1001, 1, 1, 0, 1;1002, 1, 0, 0,1)`

```
eid ||cola  ||colb|| colc   ||cold
```

New tables should look like ( created manually) : **Table 1**( with id and description)

```
id||description == Rows as (1, abc; 2, bcd; 3, cde; 4, def)
```

where abc , bcd, cde, def == are the cola, colb, colc, cold description

**Table 2** == with two columns

```
eid ||Group id
```

**Table 2** will look like below after migrating from existing table

```
Rows as (1001,1; 1001,2;1001,4;1002,1;1002,4)
```

Please suggest me how to write the query.

Comment: Query to migrate existing table to table 2

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
    insert into table2
    select col.id,table1.id FROM col
INNER JOIN table1 on case when col.cola=1 then 1 end =table1.id
UNION ALL 
select col.id,table1.id FROM col
INNER JOIN table1 on case when col.colb=1 then 2 end =table1.id
UNION ALL
select col.id,table1.id  FROM col
INNER JOIN table1 on case when col.colc=1 then 3 end =table1.id
UNION ALL 
select col.id,table1.id  FROM col
INNER JOIN table1 on case when col.cold=1 then 4 end =table1.id
```

Comment: hi danilo, thanks for replying..i forgot to mention..cola, colb,colc, cold in table 1 will be descriptions of columns from existing table it means something like this,        cola is column name in existing table but in table 1 it will like "abc"

Comment: That is, if cola is equal to 1 then its description will be 'abc', so it is true that `select col.id,table1.id FROM col
INNER JOIN table1 on case when col.cola=1 then 1 end =table1.id` or `select col.id,table1.id FROM col
INNER JOIN table1 on case when col.colb=1 then 2 end =table1.id` ...

Comment: Hi Danilo..seems like am confusing, existing table has columna, columnb, columnc, columnd, eid (values as per question).. since we are normalizing the table, divided that table into 2 tables (table 1, table2). So from existing table i need to import  data into table 2 with ids in table1